# SSRS: How to Display Checkbox on Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, checkbox, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I create a checkbox in order to display it on SSRS report. We are using an SQL query in order to fetch the data from the database. There is a field named "Revised" which returns either '0' or '1'. I need to display the output in form of checkbox.

Comment: http://kkryczka.wordpress.com/2010/12/09/how-to-display-checkbox-on-report/

Comment: Alternatively to Eric's solution, you could also make use of indicators (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633651.aspx), or simply embed an image of a checkbox in the report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Eric for sharing this useful link.
I did the same as it was suggested. For the particular textbox I used FontFamily : WingDings and then added the following expression.

=IIF(First(Fields!PdfOnly.Value, "DataSet1") =1 , chr(254), chr(111))

Comment: Or you can set the textbox placeholder to render tags as html and then put this html in: Or you can set the Placeholder expression to support HTML and then set up the following html code:

    <font face="Wingdings 2" color="green">@Html.Raw(((char)0x51).ToString())</font>

You should put in the character of the wingdings that you want.
This way, only part of the text can be wingdings.
 [Wingdings 2][1]


  [1]: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Expression: =Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.iif(Fields!IsActive.Value = "1", Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.chr(254), Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.chr(111))

Change Font To: Wingdings, 10pt, Default, Default, Default

Done